# Error when assigning local variable with same name as a global variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am seeing an error when assigning either a global or an enclosing-function local to a local variable with the same name.  The code below illustrates this issue, where `f()` runs fine, while `g()` raises an error.  It seems like python knows that `a` is being assigned locally, so it says that all references to `a` are now local, even the references before `a` is actually assigned locally.  What explains this behavior?  I am running Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit).

```
In [18]: a = 1
    ...: 
    ...: def f():
    ...:   x = a
    ...:   print x
    ...: 
    ...: def g():
    ...:   a = a
    ...:   print a
    ...:   

In [19]: f()
1

In [20]: g()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-d65ffd94a45c> in <module>()
----> 1 g()

<ipython-input-18-f3d970bdaa2b> in g()
      6 
      7 def g():
----> 8   a = a
      9   print a
     10 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Always Function has scopes and bound to its variable.[refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: I see no scoping issues here.  When `a` is first referenced, there are no local definitions of `a`, so in the answer you referenced it should move on to the locally-enclosed variables and then global variables, where `a` lives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that, within g(), you need to declare

```
global a
```

if you want to be able to modify "a" from within a function and have this effect globally visible. However, in your case, the effect of using "a" within g() is to convert this variable name to refer to a local-scope variable, which then hides the global "a" which you're attempting to use on the righthand side of your assignment, triggering the exception. This is more fully explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value). There is also a Python [FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) which explains the rules that make f() work without the need for the "global a".

Comment: Whats the long answer? :)