# Accessing global variable in function in python

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables, local-variables

I have two pieces of code:

```
def g(y):
  print(x)
x = 5 
g(x)
```

and

```
def h(y):
  x = x + 1
x = 5
h(x)
```

The first piece of code works perfectly fine printing '5' while the second piece returns:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

What does this actually mean? Is it trying to say that it tried to evaluate the line `x = x + 1` before it evaluates the line `x=5`? If that is so, why has the first piece of code not generated any error? It similarly had to evaluate the line `print(x)` before `x` was assigned a value.

I think I might have an misunderstanding how functions are called. But I do not know what it is that I got wrong.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368402/error-when-assigning-local-variable-with-same-name-as-a-global-variable/48368450#48368450.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# first block: read of global variable. 
def g(y):
  print(x)
x = 5 
g(x)

# second block: create new variable `x` (not global) and trying to assign new value to it based on on this new var that is not yet initialized.
def h(y):
  x = x + 1
x = 5
h(x)
```

If you want to use global you need to specify that explicitly with `global` keyword:

```
def h(y):
  global x
  x = x + 1
x = 5
h(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as Aiven said, or you can modify the code like this:

```
def h(y):
   x = 9
   x = x + 1
   print(x) #local x
x = 5
h(x)
print(x) #global x
```